# The problems of overlapping iOS view transfer touch time

Tags: ios, objective-c

i create a view like this:
[image: result image]

i create two Class(RedView,GreenView) that is subclass of UIView Class,and rewriting their touchsMoved:withEvent function.The code like this:

In RedView:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

NSLog(@"moved in red");}
```

In GreenView:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

NSLog(@"moved in green");}
```

Then I created as shown in the above interface，But when I slide in the blanks, found the rootViewController, redView, greenView three view touchMoved: event trigger method.why ? i don not touch redView or greenView,i just slid in the rootViewController in white space,but why the two subView method was response ?hope any answer ....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement `touchesForView:`

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if ([event touchesForView:self].count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"moved in red");
    }
}
```

Apple's doc on the touch event stream explains more: [Multitouch Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html)